# NTILE function performance in hive

Tags: sql, optimization, hive, bigdata, window-functions

Is there any way we can optimize the NTILE function run time. Currently, we have around 51M records with 17 variables. 
We are performing below query to divide the datasets in to 100 buckets.

```
create table secondary_table  
stored as orc 
as
select a.*,NTILE(100) OVER(ORDER BY score) AS score_rank
from main_table a;
```

Here score variable represents 12 digit decimal values.

As of now all the load is getting dumped to one reducer which is taking a lot of time after completing 99%. Is there any approach we can optimize it as the current query is taking around 35 min. to execute.

Appreciate any response.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite an answer, but it might provide some guidance.

The issue is the lack of `partition by` in the window function.  Replacing it with equivalent constructs using, say, `row_number()` and `count(*)` won't help.

When I have encountered this, I have been able to work around it in one of two ways.

- If there are lots of duplicates, then aggregate and use cumulative sums to define the tiles.
- Otherwise, break the values into groups.

As an example of the second.  Assuming the scores range from 0 to 1000, with pretty even distributions.  Then:

```
select t.*,
       1 + floor((t.seqnum_within + tt.running_cnt - tt.cnt - 1) * 100 / cnt)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by trunc(score) order by score) as seqnum_within
      from t
     ) t join
     (select trunc(score) as score_trunc, count(*) as cnt,
             sum(count(*)) over (order by min(score)) as running_cnt,
             sum(count(*)) over () as total_cnt
      from t
      group by trunc(score)
     ) tt
     on trunc(t.score) = score_trunc;
```

The `GROUP BY` and `JOIN` should make better use of the parallel hardware.